# What's algorithm used to solve Linear Diophantine equation: ax + by = c

Tags: algorithm, numbers

I'm looking for integers solution here. I know it has infinitely many solution derived from the first pair solution and gcd(a,b)|c. However, how could we find the first pair of solution? Is there any algorithm to solve this problem?

Thanks,
Chan

Comment: what did your web search yield?

Comment: @David Heffernan: Extended Euclidean algorithm is what I got, but I could not understand their pseudo-code written in a very weird language.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Note that there isn't always a solution. In fact, there's only a solution if `c` is a multiple of `gcd(a, b)`.

That said, you can use the [extended euclidean algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm) for this.

Here's a C++ function that implements it, assuming `c = gcd(a, b)`. I prefer to use the recursive algorithm:

```
function extended_gcd(a, b)
    if a mod b = 0
        return {0, 1}
    else
        {x, y} := extended_gcd(b, a mod b)
        return {y, x-(y*(a div b))}

int ExtendedGcd(int a, int b, int &x, int &y)
{
    if (a % b == 0)
    {
        x = 0;
        y = 1;
        return b;
    }

    int newx, newy;
    int ret = ExtendedGcd(b, a % b, newx, newy);

    x = newy;
    y = newx - newy * (a / b);
    return ret;
}
```

Now if you have `c = k*gcd(a, b)` with `k > 0`, the equation becomes:

```
ax + by = k*gcd(a, b) (1)
(a / k)x + (b / k)y = gcd(a, b) (2)
```

So just find your solution for (2), or alternatively find the solution for (1) and multiply `x` and `y` by `k`.

Comment: @IVIad: Thanks, can you briefly explain how it work? I tried to implement it using C++ but I could not get the expected result.